# regex, characters separated by comma

Tags: java, regex

I want check the format of a String. 
The formats possible are :

```
-"AZERTY"
-"AZERTY,REGULAR,AKILO"
```

I make this but I'm not sure :

```
String formatAttributes = "^[a-zA-Z0-9](,[a-zA-Z0-9])?*$";
```

It's correct ?

Comment: `"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(,[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$";`

Comment: If a value may be empty, e.g. `"ABC,,XYZ"`, then replace `+` with `*` in the regex by @PranavCBalan. And if you use the `matches()` call to check, which seems likely, then the `^` and `$` are unnecessary.

Comment: @Andreas he want to check the entire string format so there is need for `^` and `$` . as per the example I don't think that he needs to match  string like `"ABC,,XYZ"`

Comment: @PranavCBalan `matches()` will match the entire string, whether `^$` is given or not. `find()` will need the `^$` if the search needs to be anchored.

Comment: @Andreas :  I'm not familiar with regex in java :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to proceed:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+(,\\w+)*");
System.out.println(pattern.matcher("AZERTY").matches());
System.out.println(pattern.matcher("AZERTY,REGULAR,AKILO").matches());
```

**Output:**

```
true
true
```

**NB:** `\w` is a word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9] which means that underscore has been added to your initial regular expression, if you don't want it, the regexp will be `[a-zA-Z0-9]+(,[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*`

Answer (score 0):

There are several plausible solutions here. Assuming that you only want to match exactly your two examples `AZERTY` and `AZERTY,REGULAR,AKILO` where the characters can be any `a-z`.

```
^([a-z0-9]+(?:,[a-z0-9]+,[a-z0-9]+)?)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Note: this expression assumes the use of the case insensitive flag.

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/yP6lX6/1